# The Hahn-Kolmogorov Extension Theorem

Tags: mathematics

How did Hahn and Kolmogorov prove the Hahn-Kolmogorov Extension Theorem?

Comment: Are you asking for reference to original paper(s)?

Comment: @Conifold Not necessarly, but references would be beneficial.